# How to wait for all in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My code is nearly working well my problem is that only the first CSV data is logged and the lambda function ends.

I guess I need someway to wait for all `stream pipes` to end.

```js
myCsvList.forEach((myElem) => {
      const data = [];

      // setup params

      const csvFile = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream(); // works fine

      csvFile
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', function(entry) {
          data.push(entry);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log(data); // after the log of the first element on myCsvList, the code finishes. It should log all csvFiles from myCsvList
        });
});
```

I guess I need a promises or something?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `finish` event

Comment: @MrFabio_25 can you detail? I don't understand how I can wait for all the pipes are done when looping the `myCsvList`

Comment: @MrFabio_25 This doesn't look like a pipe chain. The problem is `forEach`.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Just found the right post for that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483508/nodejs-wait-until-streaming-multiple-files-is-complete-before-continuing-code
As @wenzi mentioned in his answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS - Wait Until Streaming Multiple Files Is Complete Before Continuing Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483508/nodejs-wait-until-streaming-multiple-files-is-complete-before-continuing-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change every item to Promise, then use `Promise.all()`:

```js
const getItem = (myElem) => {
  const data = [];

  // setup params

  const csvFile = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream(); // works fine

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    csvFile
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', function (entry) {
        data.push(entry);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        resolve(data); // after the log of the first element on myCsvList, the code finishes. It should log all csvFiles from myCsvList
      });
  });
};

const start = () => {
  // all promises have been finished
  return Promise.all(myCsvList.map(myElem => getItem(myElem)));
}
```

`myCsvList.map(myElem => getItem(myElem))` can get a promise list, when all promises have been resolved, it will trigger Promise.all().

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: If this CSVFile creation can fail then, I suggest that [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) is used.

Comment: Also, make sure that you reject the promise on error.

Comment: @SNikhill yes, it should add reject(). I just create a demo, not thinking an error situation.